# mysql creating table foreign key

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I've created a table :

```
CREATE TABLE users (
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,uName VARCHAR(50)
,uSecondName VARCHAR(50)
,eMail VARCHAR(50)
```

)

After this I even insert some data without any problems. But when I've tried to create new table with `FOREIGN KEY` referenced to users.id I've got an error:

```
CREATE TABLE posts(
id INT(6) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL
,pTitle VARCHAR(155) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'not_set'
,pText TEXT
,pAuthor INT(6) 
,PRIMARY KEY(id)
,CONSTRAINT fk_PerAuthor FOREIGN KEY (pAuthor)
REFERENCES users(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Did I miss something?

Comment: `users.id is` int unsigned, `posts.pAUthor` is  just `int`. They must be the same type

Comment: @a1ex07 Thank you. It's because of my inattention.